# seabornで綺麗なペアプロットを表示させたい。pairplotする時、hueの設定でLinAlgError: singular matrixと出てしまう。

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

独自データで、iris分析のようなpairplotを表示させたいです。

独自データ

```
＝カメラの
weight(重さ),
quality(画質),
price(値段),
camera(1一眼/2ミラーレス/3コンデジ/4スマホ)
```

[[1066, 2400, 215000, 1], [1274, 2400, 225000, 1], [1048, 2400, 205800, 1], [1200, 2400, 195500, 1], [970, 2400, 199000, 1], [1042, 2400, 220890, 1], [1110, 2400, 210400, 1], [1023, 2400, 195400, 1], [1024, 2400, 205000, 1], [1024, 2400, 205300, 1], [433, 2400, 105000, 2], [400, 2400, 185000, 2], [420, 2400, 179000, 2], [580, 2400, 105000, 2], [550, 2400, 165020, 2], [549, 2400, 105000, 2], [600, 2400, 185000, 2], [666, 2400, 104980, 2], [672, 2400, 130300, 2], [631, 2400, 160300, 2], [200, 2400, 26100, 3], [238, 2020, 15000, 3], [277, 2400, 25400, 3], [298, 2020, 15410, 3], [316, 2420, 25000, 3], [276, 2400, 24020, 3], [299, 1800, 20000, 3], [254, 2420, 25030, 3], [189, 2020, 24000, 3], [241, 2420, 20260, 3], [150, 1600, 3000, 4], [143, 1600, 2500, 4], [188, 1800, 3000, 4], [115, 1600, 2500, 4], [140, 1200, 2500, 4], [127, 1200, 3000, 4], [130, 1600, 2500, 4], [153, 1800, 3000, 4], [116, 1600, 2500, 4], [149, 1800, 2500, 4]]

```
# おまじない
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

import seaborn as sns
# JupyterLab で実行する際は、この行を書くことで描画できるようになります。
%matplotlib inline

# 表示を短縮
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.max_columns = 15

c_file = open('camera.csv')
c_reader = csv.reader(c_file)
c_data = list(c_reader)
c_data = [[int(elm) for elm in v] for v in c_data]#str→int
print(c_data)
print(len(c_data))

head_data = list(['weight', 'quality', 'price', 'camera'])
print(head_data)

df  = pd.DataFrame(c_data, columns=head_data)
sns.pairplot(df, hue='camera')
```

とすると、
以下のようなエラーになってしまいます。

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6c1adccc077e> in <module>
----> 1 sns.pairplot(df, hue='camera')
(略)
LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

[image: singular matrix error]

ただし、`hue='camera'`を外すと色分けはされませんが正しく表示されます。
[image: sns.pairplot(df) only]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVSBO.png)のようなplotで、カメラの種類によって色分けさせるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

多分seabornのバグではないでしょうか。
・ GitHb issues　[LinAlgError: singular matrix #1502](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1502)

Google Colab（環境は python==3.6 seaborn==0.7.1）だと同じコードで正常に表示されました。質問の方のグラフでは対角線がKDEになっていますが、こちらは対角線がヒストグラフ（柱状グラフ）になっています。上のissuesの議論ではヒストグラフにするとバグが発生しずらいようです。

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

c_data = [[1066, 2400, 215000, 1], [1274, 2400, 225000, 1], [1048, 2400, 205800, 1], [1200, 2400, 195500, 1],
 [970, 2400, 199000, 1], [1042, 2400, 220890, 1], [1110, 2400, 210400, 1], [1023, 2400, 195400, 1],
 [1024, 2400, 205000, 1], [1024, 2400, 205300, 1], [433, 2400, 105000, 2], [400, 2400, 185000, 2],
 [420, 2400, 179000, 2], [580, 2400, 105000, 2], [550, 2400, 165020, 2], [549, 2400, 105000, 2],
 [600, 2400, 185000, 2], [666, 2400, 104980, 2], [672, 2400, 130300, 2], [631, 2400, 160300, 2],
 [200, 2400, 26100, 3], [238, 2020, 15000, 3], [277, 2400, 25400, 3], [298, 2020, 15410, 3],
 [316, 2420, 25000, 3], [276, 2400, 24020, 3], [299, 1800, 20000, 3], [254, 2420, 25030, 3],
 [189, 2020, 24000, 3], [241, 2420, 20260, 3], [150, 1600, 3000, 4], [143, 1600, 2500, 4],
 [188, 1800, 3000, 4], [115, 1600, 2500, 4], [140, 1200, 2500, 4], [127, 1200, 3000, 4],
 [130, 1600, 2500, 4], [153, 1800, 3000, 4], [116, 1600, 2500, 4], [149, 1800, 2500, 4]]

head_data = list(['weight', 'quality', 'price', 'camera'])
df  = pd.DataFrame(c_data, columns=head_data)
sns.pairplot(df, hue='camera')
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: すばらしいです、無事私も表示させることができました…！ありがとうございました！ローカル環境のjupyternotebookですと、エラーになるようです。(python==3.6 seaborn==0.9.0) diag_kind='hist'を指定してもダメでした。Google Colabで表示させたところ、対角線の指定ナシで表示させることができました。